# Why Do I use :server-items-length" props at vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hello I'm using vuetify to implement pagination by using `<v-data-table>`  and `<v-pagination>`
I wonder why :server-items-length prop is used when requesting data from the backend.
Previously, I implemented it by using @page-count in v-data-table and pageCount as prop in v-pagination.
I am curious about the difference between the two methods and the advantages of using server-items-length.

before

```
 <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :search="search"
      :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
      @page-count="pageCount = $event"></v-data-table>

<v-pagination v-model="page"
        :length="pageCount"
        :total-visible="totalVisible">
```

after

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :server-items-length="postLenth">

<v-pagination v-model="page" :length="pageCount" :total-visible="10"
```

Answer (score 3):

When pagination is done locally in the client by Vuetify, Vuetify already has all the items and can count the total length of the items and divide it into pages, using items-per-page prop.

But, when pagination is done on the server-side, Vuetify might only have items for the one page and needs information about the total length of the items in DB, to be able to display the total amount of pages.

Passing server-items-length prop will tell Vuetify how many items there are in total.

Comment: I'd add it's usually a better idea to avoid get all the data at once and pass it to the table. Instead, you should use the real purpose of pagination : load data little by little to avoid overload and avoid query that could take a lot of time to retrieve a large amount of data.